# Как исправить дублирование при SQL запросе с использованием MAX

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

```
Shipment has_many :movements
Movement belongs_to :shipment


@shipments = Shipment.latest_movement

scope :latest_movement, -> do
  joins(
    <<-'QUERY'.strip_sql
        LEFT OUTER JOIN movements
          ON shipments.id = movements.shipment_id
          AND movements.moved_at = (
            SELECT MAX(movements.moved_at)
            FROM movements
            WHERE shipments.id = movements.shipment_id
          )
  QUERY
  ).includes(:movements, :origin, :destination, :location)
end
```

Данный код на странице `shipments` выводит список с данными о `shipment` и о его `movement` с самым свежим `movement.moved_at`.

Проблема в том, что если у `shipment` есть два `movements` с одинаковым `movement.moved_at` то на странице списка `shipments` появляется дубликат и один и тот же `shipment` отображается два раза.

Как в sql запрос добавть еще одно условие к `MAX(movements.moved_at)`, что бы если максимальная дата `movements.moved_at` найдена у двух и более `movements`, из них оставался бы тот у которого `movements.created_at` больше

**UPDATE:**
полный запрос на Rails

```
@shipments = Shipment.visible_to(current_user).latest_movement.filter(filter_params)
                     .reorder(sort).page(params[:page])

Started GET "/shipments?mawb=262-12345678&origin=&destination=&moved_at=&location=&status_code=&flight_data=&search="
```

в SQL запрос выглядит примерно так

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM "shipments"
LEFT OUTER JOIN movements
ON shipments.id = movements.shipment_id
AND movements.moved_at = (
 SELECT MAX(movements.moved_at)
 FROM movements
 WHERE shipments.id = movements.shipment_id
)
WHERE shipments.mawb = '262-12345678'
```

База на PostgreSQL

Answer (score 0):

Ну постгресс поддерживает оконные функции, так что будет что-то вроде

```
AND (movements.moved_at, movements.created_at) = (
    SELECT x.moved_at, x.created_at
    FROM (
        SELECT movements.shipment_id
             , movements.moved_at
             , movements.created_at
             , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY movements.shipment_id 
                                  ORDER BY movements.moved_at DESC
                                         , movements.created_at DESC
                                 ) rn
        FROM movements
        ) x
    WHERE x.rn = 1
      AND shipments.id = x.shipment_id
    )
```

хотя всё это разумнее сделать подзапросом в секции FROM, а не коррелированным в секции WHERE.

Answer (score 0):

Можно выборку `MAX(moved_at)` заменить на выборку **уникального** поля (я выбрал первичный ключ) **одной** записи (`LIMIT 1`) из множества, отсортированного по убыванию `moved_at`, а затем `created_at`.

```rb
scope :latest_movement, -> do
  joins(
    <<-'QUERY'.strip_sql
        LEFT OUTER JOIN movements
          ON shipments.id = movements.shipment_id
          AND movements.id = (
            SELECT movements.id
            FROM movements
            WHERE shipments.id = movements.shipment_id
            ORDER BY movements.moved_at DESC, movements.created_at DESC
            LIMIT 1
          )
  QUERY
  ).includes(:movements, :origin, :destination, :location)
end
```

...хотя мне не очень нравится это решение. Но оно, интуитивно, не медленнее того, что у вас.